# Initializing constant character pointer of a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constants

I am trying to create a `Person` class in which I have decided to keep the name and gender constant. Here is the class definition:

```
class Person
{
        const char *name;
        int age;
        const char *gen;

        protected:
        Person(const char *, const int ,const char *);   // I want to use this class as a Base class

        public:
        ~Person(); 
}
```

Now my problem is how to initialize the constant data members. I know that I have to use *initialization lists* for this task but even then how do I allocate memory for the char pointers with `new`? Also I cannot initialize these pointers in the constructor body. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: the pointer is not constant but the pointed characters are. More than that, the contructor is `protected` so how do you plan to construct the object ? Give an example of how this class will be used.

Comment: I want to use this class as a base class for Student like classes @norisknofun

Comment: @norisknofun Can you please tell me the difference in the two things you said about const characters. I have never really understood the difference.

Comment: @SouravKanta Why not use a (`const`) `std::string`, so that you don't have to think about allocation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the initializer list as following, you don't need to allocate the char array in this construction. I have simplified the class, as your question is about the `const char*`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
    public:
        Person(const char* name, const std::string better_name) : 
            name(name), better_name(better_name) {}
        void print_name() 
        { 
            std::cout << name << " and " << better_name << std::endl; 
        }
    private:
        const char* name;
        const std::string better_name;
};

int main()
{
    Person person("Billy", "Better Billy");
    person.print_name();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is memory allocated for name ?

Comment: Also isn't `Billy` stored in the read only memory? I want to allocate new memory in heap for the name and gender.

Comment: @Sourav Kanta I would use std::string

Comment: @SouravKanta, and why do you want to have a short const char on the heap? I have added the `std::string` to the answer as an illustration. Its contents are stored on the heap.

Comment: Typical C/C++ problem: while copying (in any sense) external data in constructor, what memory model do You use inside? In Your constructor, name can only lead to static string. Constructing Person in the future name with dynamic string, will give UB. Sample with const std::string better_name is ... better :)

Comment: @JacekCz. At least the naming of the variables makes sense then :)